# where to place images folder in Kohana PHP?

Tags: php, kohana

I have a page with some HTML  in it.
and I need to set the src property to the location of pictures.

How can I achieve that with Kohana PHP ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where the images are located.  In a standard Kohana install, the files are located in your document root and are accessible with the url::file() call, eg:

```
<?php echo url::file("images/foo.gif") ?>
```

would refer to:

```
http://example.com/images/foo.gif
```

Reference: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/url#file

Comment: This appears to apply to Kohana 2, not K3.